# How to select keys of objects in a JSON array using MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I'm working with a table that uses a JSON column to store **questions** and **answers** as an array of objects where the key is the **question** and the value is the **answer**.

The questions are user generated so the keys can literally be anything.

For example:

| id | questions |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"Favourite Food?": "Pizza"}, {"Age?": "12"}] |
| 2 | [{"Where do you live?": "France"}, {"Are you ok?", "No, not really"}] |

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible using MySQL to query this data and get a result that looks like this:

| question | answer |
| --- | --- |
| "Favourite Food?" | "Pizza" |
| "Age?" | "12" |
| "Where do you live?" | "France" |
| "Are you ok?" | "No, not really" |

I didn't think this would be too hard but quickly realized this is probably way out of my depth with MySQL!

The main struggle here is that I can't seem to figure out how to extract the keys when they're buried in an Array like this and I don't know what the names of the keys would be.

The closest I can get is a query that looks like this:

```sql
select j.* from ats_applicants,
                JSON_TABLE(additional_fields, "$[*].*" COLUMNS ( question varchar(100) PATH '$', answer varchar(100) PATH '$'))
                    as j where additional_fields is not null;
```

Problem is this only gives me the values of the objects and not the keys like this:

| question | answer |
| --- | --- |
| "Pizza" | "Pizza" |
| "12" | "12" |
| "etc" | "etc" |

I have no good reason for doing this by the way. Purely scratching an itch because I saw this problem come up and thought it would be simple -- and maybe it is -- I just don't see how to do this!

Thanks in advance

Comment: that is a bad deasign for json, which uses the same keys ever time to process equal data

Comment: Appreciate the comment but that's irrelevant. Not my design. "Bad" is subjective. This worked for someone to solve a problem at some point etc. This isn't a call for judgment. I'm just curious if what I asked is possible.

Comment: json is like xml and databases, you will **not** have for every column another  name  but that is whyt you made, so design is **very** bad

Comment: @nbk **Very** insightful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier if you store the JSON differently:

| id | questions |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"question": "Favourite Food?", "answer": "Pizza"}, {"question": "Age?": "answer": "12"}] |
| 2 | [{"question": "Where do you live?", "answer": "France"}, {"question": "Are you ok?", "answer": "No, not really"}] |

Then you can use JSON_TABLE() to map the fields into columns:

```
SELECT j.* 
FROM ats_applicants 
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(additional_fields, '$[*]' COLUMNS ( 
    question varchar(100) PATH '$.question', 
    answer varchar(100) PATH '$.answer'
  )
) AS j
WHERE additional_fields IS NOT NULL;
```

But it would be *even easier* if you don't use JSON at all, but just store each question and answer in a row by itself:

| id | applicant_id | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Favorite Food? | Pizza |
| 2 | 1 | Age? | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | Where do you live? | France |
| 4 | 2 | Are you ok? | No, not really |

People are too eager to use JSON these days. Normal rows and columns are easier and more efficient.

---

Re your comment:

Yes, I believe it's possible, but it's more trouble than it's worth.

You can't use JSON_TABLE() directly, because the objects don't have consistent key names.

So you would need to:

1. Split the array into one object per row by joining to a set of integers. For example, use a temp table or a CTE.
2. For each object, use JSON_KEYS() to get the key names into an array.
3. Use those key names in calls to JSON_EXTRACT().

Below is a solution I got to work. To my mind, this is utterly stupid to use a data model that requires such complex code to do the simplest task.

```
WITH RECURSIVE n AS (
  SELECT 0 AS n
  UNION SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < 1
), 
pair AS (
  SELECT id, n.n, JSON_EXTRACT(additional_fields, CONCAT('$[', n.n, ']')) AS pair
  FROM n CROSS JOIN ats_applicants
),
q AS (
  SELECT id, n, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(pair), '$[0]')) AS question
  FROM pair
)
SELECT id, q.question, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(pair.pair, CONCAT('$."', q.question, '"'))) AS answer
FROM q JOIN pair USING (id, n)
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------+
| id | question           | answer         |
+----+--------------------+----------------+
|  1 | Age?               | 12             |
|  1 | Favourite Food?    | Pizza          |
|  2 | Are you ok?        | No, not really |
|  2 | Where do you live? | France         |
+----+--------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for taking the time! I realize this would be easier if the JSON was stored differently. Also I realize that this doesn't need to be stored as JSON. My question isn't, "is there an easier way" or "is this a good idea". Just "is this possible?"

Thanks again!

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to solve this even if it seems "stupid". If it wasn't clear from the original question, this isn't something I'm actually doing IRL. The data is a real life example but the query isn't. And the data isn't stored like that anymore anyway so it's validity is moot. Was really just trying to stretch my knowledge of SQL and you helped me with that, so thank you!

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry if I came off as harsh. But I try to find solutions that are economical in all senses: for initial code development, future code maintenance and debugging, and also runtime performance. I find storing data in a relational database in JSON format frequently conflicts with all three of these, so I want to discourage people from adopting JSON-based solutions.

Comment: But I agree that expanding your knowledge of SQL is a good thing, and seeing a concrete example of how using JSON makes queries more complex is undoubtedly educational.